# how to extractble text from text using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

hello everyone i try to extract the "SID" value from the text file bellow using a (for/f )with batch file when run query after extracting SID i need to assigned value of SID to this command " alter system kill  session ‘ SID_value'
so please anyone have any idea how to do it or any other solution could be use.

output:
(SID, S#=5694, 55482)
=> 55482
alter system kill  session ‘ 55482'

---

**query_result.txt:**

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Mar 12 09:28:16 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> 
LOGCDE@DOM\AMANSAPP1 (SID, S#=5694, 55482) is blocking GENCDE@DDOM\SA=V M-MOTOR-WS (SID, S#=959, 36066)

LOGCDE@DOM\AMANSAPP1 (SID, S#=5694, 55482) is blocking GENCDE@DDOM\SA=V M-MOTOR-WS (SID, S#=1025, 36066)

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: FYI you can eliminate much of the extra crud for a scripted/canned Oracle SQLPLUS query with the `-S` option; see the documentation or help message. But you didn't ask that question and this is would be the wrong stack for it anyway.

Comment: Windows `CMD` is *not* **MS-DOS**!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q42744864.txt"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'findstr /L /i /c:"is blocking " "%filename1%"'
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=2*delims=()" %%m IN ("%%a") DO (
  ECHO(%%n|FINDSTR /b /L /C:" is blocking ">NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims==, " %%p IN ("%%m") DO (
    IF "%%p"=="SID" IF "%%q"=="S#" ECHO(alter system kill session '%%s'
   )
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q42744864.txt` containing your data for my testing.

First, read the file using `findstr` to find lines containing `/i` case-insensitive, `/L` literally `/c:"this string"`. Ass ign each such line found to `%%a`.

Next, tokenise `%%a` using `(` and `)` and assign the part between the parentheses to `%%m` and that after the second parenthesis to `%%n`

echo `%%n` into `findstr` testing for lines that `/b` begin.../L and /C: I've already covered. Dispose of the output from `findstr` with `>nul` - `findstr` will set `errorlevel` to 0 of the string is found, 1 otherwise.

If the errorlevel is 0, tokenise the contents of the parentheses in `%%m` using `=`, `,` and <kbd>Space</kbd>, so the `SID` should go to `%%p`, `S#` to `%%q`, whatever the number is following `S#` to `%%r` and the required number to `%%s`.

If `%%p` and `%%q` check out, show the required line.